# Using relatedTo programatically?

Tags: plugin-development, entries, elementtype, queries

I'm trying to extend the ElementCriteriaModel using the guide here:

https://blog.tighten.co/craft-cms-building-complex-queries-by-extending-the-elementcriteriamodel

However I need to re-implement `relatedTo` keyword somehow. This is what I have so far but doesn't seem to work at all

```
    $criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Category);
    $criteria->slug = 'seasonal-event';
    $criteria->limit = 1;

    $category = $criteria->find();

    $this->criteria->relatedTo = array(
        'targetElement' => $category
    );

    return $this;
```

Comment: Any errors thrown?

Answer (score 3):

You're using `$criteria`, but attempting to set the `relatedTo` property on `$this->criteria`.

Assuming that's not the issue, have you tried using `$criteria->setAttribute('relatedTo', ['targetElement' => $category])`?

I've found `setAttribute` to be more reliable than the `ElementCriteriaModel` magic methods.